# Tap on UITabelViewCell doesn't detected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to detect when a `UITableViewCell` is tap in my `UITableView`.

This is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let section = indexPath.section
        let row = indexPath.row
        if section == 2 && row == 0 {
            //OTHER CODE
        }
}
```

But doesn't works.

And this is the settings of Attributes Inspector of my `UITableView`:

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:**

My full code:

```
class UserPageWeeklyInformationsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    //VARIABLES

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //OTHER CODE
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

        let header:UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView

        let fontSize = header.textLabel!.font.pointSize
        header.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: fontSize)
        header.textLabel!.frame = header.frame
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let section = indexPath.section
        let row = indexPath.row
        print(section)
        print(row)
        if section == 2 && row == 0 {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("goToPost", object: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

My `UITableViewController` is contained in a `Container View` that is situated in a `UIViewController`. In the main `UITableViewController` I implement the `Tap Gesture Recognizer`.

**EDIT:**

I resolve the problem removing the Gesture Recognizer in main `UIViewController`.

Comment: Is didSelectRowAtIndexPath even called? Did you implement willSelectRowAtIndexPath perhaps?

Comment: Section 2 in the code is the 3rd section in your table. Are you clicking the correct row?

Comment: @ff10 I didn't mplement willSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @Shades the method is never called.

Comment: As it has been suggested: did you set the UITableViewDelegate to the class where this method has been implemented?

Comment: @MatteoSerpentoni, Probably you haven't set the delegate of your TableView

Comment: @ff10 My class is a UITableViewController.

Comment: How do you know the method is never called? You're only checking for the selection of one specific row? If you show the rest of the code, someone can help you

Comment: @Shades i try to print the section and row out of the if condition and it never print

Comment: I don't understand why -1.

Comment: What do you have in the storyboard? You could have a UI element that is handling the tap before the tableview receives it.

Comment: @ChadPavliska my UITableViewController is contained in a Container View that is situated in a UIViewController. In the main UITableViewController I implement the Tap Gesture Recognizer. Is this a problem?

Comment: @MatteoSerpentoni I moved my comment to an answer and expanded it. Can you accept that answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you have in the storyboard? You could have a UI element that is handling the tap before the tableview receives it.

The issue is a UITapGestureRecognizer was handling the tap gesture before the UITableView saw it.

Note: Rather than remove the tap gesture, you could experiment with setting `UITapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to check if you set the class as UITableViewDelegate and you set it as

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

Comment: why given the negative Vote, may be this answer also useful

Answer (score 0):

Being that your table is in fact embedded into a ViewController, you have to make the table an outlet of that ViewController and put all of the code for the table into that VC's class. Note the removal of the word "override" from the functions.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTable.delegate = self
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

        let header:UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView

        let fontSize = header.textLabel!.font.pointSize
        header.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: fontSize)
        header.textLabel!.frame = header.frame
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let section = indexPath.section
        let row = indexPath.row
        print(section)
        print(row)
        if section == 2 && row == 0 {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("goToPost", object: nil)
        }
    }
}
```